# Parking lot project error: when using a scanner. NoSuchElementException

Tags: kotlin, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

I'll appreciate all your help.
I've been working on a course project where I have to make a parking lot that registers cars. When I use it in my IDE it works fine but when I run it through the platforms tests, in the first one, there's no problem but when the second iteration reaches the "**when (val command = scanner.next())**" in the **createOrder** fun, it crashes with the error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Exception in test #1

Probably your program run out of input (Scanner tried to read more than expected).

java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
    at parking.ParkingLot.createOrder(Main.kt:39)
    at parking.ParkingLot.start(Main.kt:31)
    at parking.MainKt.main(Main.kt:6)
    at parking.MainKt.main(Main.kt)

Please find below the output of your program during this failed test.
Note that the '>' character indicates the beginning of the input line.

---

> park KA-01-HH-1234 White
White car parked in spot 1.
```

the idea is that the test inputs many cars but it crashes when trying to do the second input

this is my code (sorry if my code is messy, I'm still learning)

```
import java.util.*

fun main() {
    ParkingLot.start()
}

class Car(val regNumber: String = "", val color: String = "") {

}

class Order(val command: String) {
    lateinit var regNum: String
    lateinit var color: String
    lateinit var spot: String
    lateinit var status: String

}

object ParkingLot {
    val spaces: Array<Pair<String?, Car?>> = Array(20) { Pair(null, null) }
    const val occupied = "occupied"
    const val park = "park"
    const val leave = "leave"
    const val exit = "exit"

    fun start() {
        val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
        do {
            val order = createOrder(scanner)
            interaction(order, scanner)
        } while (order.command != exit)
    }

   fun createOrder(scanner: Scanner): Order {

        when (val command = scanner.next()) {
            park -> {
                val parkOrder = Order(command)
                parkOrder.regNum = scanner.next()
                parkOrder.color = scanner.next()
                parkOrder.status = "valid"
                return parkOrder
            }
            leave -> {
                val retrieveOrder = Order(command)
                retrieveOrder.spot = scanner.next()
                retrieveOrder.status = "valid"
                return retrieveOrder
            }
            exit -> {
                val exitOrder = Order(command)
                exitOrder.status = "valid"
                return exitOrder
            }

            else -> {
                val incorrectOrder = Order(command)
                incorrectOrder.status = "invalid"
                return incorrectOrder
            }
        }
    }


    fun interaction(order: Order, scanner: Scanner) {

        if (order.command == park) {
//            val toParkCar = Car(order.regNum, order.color)
            park(Car(order.regNum, order.color))
        }
        if (order.command == leave) {
            leave(order)
        }
        if (order.command == exit) return
//TODO update the error msg to include exit command
        if (order.status == "invalid") println("\"${order.command}\" isn't a valid , either use \"park\" or \"leave\"")
//        scanner.close()
    }

    fun park(car: Car) {
        for ((index, item) in spaces.withIndex()) {
            if (item.first == null) {
                spaces[index] = Pair(occupied, car)
                println("${car.color} car parked in spot ${index + 1}.")
                return
            }
        }
        println("Sorry, the parking lot is full.")
    }

    fun leave(order: Order) {
        if (spaces[order.spot.toInt() - 1].first == occupied) {
            spaces[order.spot.toInt() - 1] = Pair(null, null)
            println("Spot ${order.spot} is free.")
        } else {
            println("There is no car in spot ${order.spot}.")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the code that contains the assert that produces "java.lang.AssertionError: Exception in test #1"?  Usually, an assert going off is meant to tell you something specific, as it's testing that something is or isn't true.  If you know where that assert is failing, a key piece of information may be what it is asserting...that is, what is the boolean expression in the assert statement?  If you find this assertion code, please add it to your question.  Also, do you have a stack trace that came with that error message?  If so, please put that in your question.

Comment: Ok I'll add the stack trace.
I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but what is the assert and how can I get it?

Comment: The statement "assert <boolean expression>" is something you put in your code to double-check an assumption you're making.  They don't (or shouldn't at least) effect the logic of your program.  They're there to let you know if something you assumed about how your code runs isn't actually true.

Comment: How are you feeding the input to your program.  Could it just be that the problem is what the code is telling you...that you aren't giving it enough input?

Comment: Oh ok, I am not double checking. I did try it with "scanner.hasNext()" but It didn't work. and the tests feed the input, I'm not sure how it does it

Comment: ...but something in your code is.  That's why you get "java.lang.AssertionError: Exception in test #1".  It's saying something is wrong, but it isn't telling you what is wrong.  If you could see the statement itself in the code, it might tell you what's really wrong.  Do you have a test program that runs your code?  If so, do you have the source code for it?

Comment: Oh ok, the asertion is not done by me but by the tests of the platform (Edu Tools from jetbrains).

Comment: If I include an if(scanner.hasNext()), it throws the error saying "Error in line 1: "White car parked in spot 1." instead of "White car parked in spot 2."

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I noticed this is a problem for the JetBrains plugin. I don't know why but the solution was taking the scanner out of the function and directly in the main loop.